# custom delete method using autowired bean in spring boot repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a possibility inside spring boot to write a custom delete method with an autowired bean inside it. I will try to explain it:

Basically, what I currently have is:

- a database table which stores asset metadata (uploader, friendly filename, ...)
- a storage bucket (in my case from Azure) which stores the actual asset file data

When my database-asset is deleted, I want to be able to also delete/modify my bucket-asset.

Idealy, I would like to be able to do:

```java
@Repository
public abstract class AssetJpaRepository implements JpaRepository<Asset, Long> {

    public abstract Asset findByUuid(String uuid);

    public abstract Asset findOneByFriendlyName(String friendlyName);
    
    @Autowired
    private BlobContainerClient assetContainerClient;

    @Override
    public void delete(Asset asset) {
        BlobClient assetClient = assetContainerClient.getBlobClient(asset.getFileReference());
        assetClient.delete();
    }
}
```

The problem now is that Spring Boot won't initialize AssetJpaRepository as a repository.

Is there a way I can do this cleanly?

Note: deleting the bucket-asset on service level is not an option, since I have parent entities which will call the asset delete method when the parent is deleted.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try @Query annotation and see if that works.

Comment: In what way? How can I use `@Query` to access the `assetContainerClient` variable/bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as another approach.

In AssetJpaRepository.java

```java
public interface AssetJpaRepository
implements JpaRepository<Asset, Long>, AssetJpaRepositoryCustom {

    Asset findByUuid(String uuid);

    Asset findOneByFriendlyName(String friendlyName);
}
```

In AssetJpaRepositoryCustom.java

```java
public interface AssetJpaRepository implements AssetJpaRepositoryCustom {
    void delete(Asset asset);
}
```

In AssetJpaRepositoryImpl.java

```java
public class AssetJpaRepositoryImpl implements AssetJpaRepositoryCustom {
    private final BlobContainerClient assetContainerClient;

    public BlobContainerClient(BlobContainerClient assetContainerClient) {
        this.assetContainerClient = assetContainerClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Asset asset) {
        BlobClient assetClient = assetContainerClient.getBlobClient(asset.getFileReference());
        assetClient.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly** This is not a good approach you should Create AssetJpaRepository `Interface` and then create a separate class and implement this `Interface`
**Secondly** you create `Native Query` with `@Query`(Delete query)  Annotation on the top of the method.